# Make Human Import

Tags: texturing, uv, makehuman

For some reason, I am unable to import a Make Human model into Blender without losing the texture binding and their settings. I have been following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MGs6Zv1pl9o) and when importing my model into blender, there are no textures. Can someone help me?

What I did was, make a model in MakeHuman. Then I exported as a Dae file without changing any settings. I opened up Blender and imported the Model using the default settings. When I render it, the model has no textures.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed the problem. Apparently the Textures must be in the same folder as the .dae file itself, and won't work if they are in a sub-directory.

So just drag all the textures to the same folder as your .dae file is in, delete the now empty texture folder (if you want) and now you can import the COLLADA into Blender.

Comment: This by the way is the most common problem when importing models from other sources into Blender. If the Textures won't show up just drop them into the same folder or reassign them.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend export with mhx2 exporter in MakeHuman and using mhx2 importer in Blender. This work fine and is developing exactly for using with Blender. Why you make your life more complicated using 3rd party format?

Or you can make new materials using exported textures manually. UVs should be right.

Comment: The MHX2 file format is a third party file format. You have to manually download and install the makehuman and blender addons which you can [find here](https://bitbucket.org/ThomasMakeHuman/mhx2-makehuman-exchange/src)

Comment: It is primary developed for import rigged meshes from MakeHuman to Blender. It is developed by MakeHuman developers, only in other project. Dae is devolepded by Sony. Sony has nothing with MakeHuman or Blender. So what is and what is not "third party" software? :-) ;-)

Comment: The projects may share developers but it is not part of the makehuman or blender development - as an external project it falls into third party. If it was an official format it would be included with the official makehuman releases. Either way we have to download the addons and install them for both programs.

Comment: OK, you are right. "3rd party" was not accurate expression in this case. But please don't play with words. :-) The point is that mhx2 is develop exactly for situations like this and for that is better using it than using any "outside" format. I thing we can agree :-)

Comment: The thing with the Dae export is the UVs are already right. So there is no need going through the hassle to download a program, download a plugin (which I actually did when I was trying to find a way to get the textures to show up) to make it work. Anyways isn't mhx deprecated in the latest version of makehuman?